# Disable the Custom Internal CSS added by theme.json for Certain Pages

Tags: theme-development, themes

I know that WordPress v5.8 has just been released and I have started using the `theme.json` for managing some basic stuffs on the Gutenberg side. But as I have started using it, I have seen a couple of things:

The custom internal CSS added by WordPress after compiling the `theme.json` file to each and every page. Does anyone know how to stop adding it on certain pages? For example if I have a custom home page or on archive pages where Gutenberg is not being used, there is no sense to load this internal CSS by WordPress. I was wondering if anyone figured out any filters to conditionally disable the internal CSS output for certain pages.

Here is how it looks:
[image: theme.json internal CSS added by WordPress]

P.S.: I've already checked the two URLs about the `theme.json` documentation, but they didn't help much regarding the queries that I had. These are are links I have already checked:

- [Global Settings & Styles (theme.json)](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/)
- [Introducing theme.json in WordPress 5.8](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/25/introducing-theme-json-in-wordpress-5-8/)

Comment: Can you pick one question and edit out the rest? We have a 1 question per question policy. If you have multiple questions, you should open multiple questions, don't bundle them together, it _significantly_ reduces the chances of an answer as now nobody can write an answer unless they answer all of your questions and get all those answers are correct. Remember, this isn't a discussion forum.

Comment: Hey, @TomJNowell I've edited this question and opened a new question for the second question. Link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/393085/50584

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can look into the [wp_enqueue_global_styles()](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/b2be104b9d8905640bd3e967d2633eec46eec55c/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2273) function, that calls
[wp_should_load_separate_core_block_assets()](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/b2be104b9d8905640bd3e967d2633eec46eec55c/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2374) and see it contains e.g. the `should_load_separate_core_block_assets` [filter](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/b2be104b9d8905640bd3e967d2633eec46eec55c/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2342) but we can't disable the global styles on the front-end, using this [filter](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/b2be104b9d8905640bd3e967d2633eec46eec55c/src/wp-includes/script-loader.php#L2285) because of:

```
/*
 * Global styles should be printed in the head when loading all styles combined.
 * The footer should only be used to print global styles for classic themes with separate core assets enabled.
 *
 * See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53494.
 */
if ( ( ! $separate_assets && doing_action( 'wp_footer' ) ) || ( $separate_assets && doing_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' ) ) ) {
    return;
}
```

where it's hooked in two places, either header or footer:

```
// Global styles can be enqueued in both the header and the footer. 
// See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53494.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_enqueue_global_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_global_styles', 1 );
```

So ticket [53494](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/53494) is also useful and the 5.8 dev [notes](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/07/01/block-styles-loading-enhancements-in-wordpress-5-8/).

For full-site-editing themes with *separate block style loading* **on** or **off** and classical themes with it **off**, one can dequeue it on the archives with:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () { 
    is_archive () && wp_dequeue_style ( 'global-styles' );
}, 11 );
```

since it's enqueued on `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook with priority 10.

For classical themes with *separate block style loading* **on**:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function () { 
    is_archive () && wp_dequeue_style ( 'global-styles' );
}, 2 );
```

since it's enqueued on `wp_footer` hook with priority 1.

But we note that themes, patterns and other plugins might depend on this.

Comment: Yes, I looked into the WP codebase and came to the same conclusion. I used the dequeue option and it worked perfectly.

Comment: hehe didn't notice your answer ;-) I will delete mine ;-)

Comment: No keep it. I will accept your answer as it has more information and good linking to the other maters.

Answer (score 4):

After digging through the WordPress v5.8 codebase, I finally found a way, it seems the only way to disable showing those `theme.json` based generated internal CSS on certain pages are by doing the following:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() : void {
    // Dequeue the styles added by theme.json file
    wp_dequeue_style('global-styles');
});
```

So, if you want to add certain logics to it, you can do that as well, for example:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() : void {
    if( is_front_page() ) {
        // Dequeue the styles added by theme.json file
        wp_dequeue_style('global-styles');
    }
});
```

Hope this helps others.

Note: The above PHP code is written for PHP v8, so if you are using a lower PHP version, you can remove the return type declaration i.e. `: void` before the first parenthesis of the function opening.