# How to disable the gradient and font size internal CSS added by WordPress when using theme.json

Tags: theme-development, themes

While using the recently introduced `theme.json` file to manage the theme defaults, I have seen something weird. That is even if the `customGradient`, `customFontSize` set to `false`, WordPress is still adding the bunch of styles related the the gradients and font sizes in the internal CSS added by the system.

Here is an example `theme.json` I am using:

```json
{
    "version": 1,
    "settings": {
        "color": {
            "customGradient": false,
            "link": false,
            "palette": [
                {
                    "name": "Black",
                    "slug": "black",
                    "color": "#000000"
                }
            ]
        },
        "layout": {
            "contentSize": "1296px"
        },
        "spacing": {
            "customMargin": false,
            "customPadding": false,
            "units": [ "px", "em", "rem", "vh", "vw" ]
        },
        "typography": {
            "customFontSize": false,
            "customLineHeight": true,
            "dropCap": false
        }
    }
}
```

But despite that, when I check the page source I see at the internal CSS added by WordPress has bunch of CSS related to gradients and font sizes. If anyone knows how to disable them, it would be really helpful.

As we are all new to this new `theme.json` relm, I think helping each other will be the best way to navigate this new world.

P.S.: I've already checked the two URLs about the `theme.json` documentation, but they didn't help much regarding the queries that I had. These are are links I have already checked:

- [Global Settings & Styles (theme.json)](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/)
- [Introducing theme.json in WordPress 5.8](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/25/introducing-theme-json-in-wordpress-5-8/)

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks.